# How to make a react-strap Button responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

How do I make a `react-strap` [Button](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/card/) contined in a Card responsive?

**Current behaviour**, as you see all the buttons in the card sort becomes a big ball:

[image: error1]

Or when I try to make the window smaller this is what happens:

[image: error2]

**The Expected Behavior** would be a more organized layout both when I make the window bigger or smaller, something like below:

[image: organized]

Belwo the code I am using:

```
                        </CardText>
                        <div class="btn-toolbar">
                            <Button className="btn mr-3">Project Notes</Button>
                            <Button className="btn mr-3">Abstract</Button>
                            <Button className="btn mr-3">Location Map</Button>
                            <Button className="btn mr-3">Distances and Contours</Button>

                            <Button className="btn mr-3">Borrow Area Info</Button>
                            <Button className="btn mr-3">Solicitation</Button>
                            <Button className="btn mr-3">Specifications</Button>
                            <Button className="btn mr-3">Amendments</Button>
                            <Button className="btn mr-3">Plans</Button>
                        </div>
                    </CardBody>
                </Card>
```

**What I have done so far:**

I have been doing a lot of research as I just started using the great tool of `react-strap`. And if you go inside the documentation there are several interesting application on how to handle the cards.
I think the problem might be in the `.css` file. I don't have any settings in particular for that because I don't know if the card can be affected.

Maybe should I use a grid-layout? Or am I going in an opposite direction?

Please point to the right direction.

Comment: Maybe try using the grid, within the card?

Comment: Thanks for reading the question. How can I do that? Could you provide an example that I can integrate in the code?

Comment: You should also consider whether or not buttons are the right UI for a list like that. Have you considered using text links instead? See https://ux.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this. Of course you'll need to play around with the grid:

```
<CardBody>
    <Row>
      <Col>
         <Button >Project Notes</Button>
      </Col>
      <Col>
         <Button >Project Notes</Button>
      </Col>
      <Col>
         <Button >Project Notes</Button>
      </Col>
      <Col>
         <Button >Project Notes</Button>
      </Col>

    </Row>
    <Row style={{marginTop:'20px'}}>
      <Col>
         <Button >Project Notes</Button>
      </Col>
      <Col>
         <Button >Project Notes</Button>
      </Col>
      <Col>
         <Button >Project Notes</Button>
      </Col>
      <Col>
         <Button >Project Notes</Button>
      </Col>

    </Row>

</CardBody>
```

The docs: https://reactstrap.github.io/components/layout/